# Where to store large assets for Unity Augmented Reality game on Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, augmented-reality, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have an app called 3Dhologirlfriend that can be deployed to the Hololens or Meta Augmented Reality devices. I have read that it is not good practice to store large assets in a Unity executable so we are looking to store the assets somewhere else and then download them at runtime.  I have researched this a bit and found the concept of an asset bundle.  My question is where to store this asset bundle so that it is secure and cannot be downloaded by anything other than the Unity app.

Comment: E.g. on a server secured with an authentication key which only the App "knows"?

Comment: This Android/IOS guide could be adapted for UWP and fits your requirements pretty well I think https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/start

Comment: I've heard that AWS buckets are the way to go here because of the security.  I guess Firebase would also quality if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the asset bundle from a remote HTTP server using [UnityWebRequest and AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html).
UnityWebRequest can be configured to work with HTTPS and client certificates.
There are many places to host your file, the details of which are probably out of scope (AWS buckets, google firebase, self hosting a server, etc..).

Comment: I've heard that AWS buckets are the way to go here because of the security.  I guess Firebase would also quality if that is the case.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 Yeah unless you're a security engineer I'd suggest paying someone to be hosting your files and managing access control.  Bear in mind you have to also think about your client-side security, eg how your app stores the credentials for AWP/GCP - https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20304/194940